# Magento2 Override Price Logic

Tags: magento2, price, magento-2.1, special-price

We have a custom extension that adds fields for multiple vendors.
How can we override Magento Price logic to make calculations for price and special price according to that fields.

I have seen the [Magento pricing library](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/architecture/behavior/pricing.html), but as a newbie to Magento2 I'm looking for some examples on how to override price and special price calculations process.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was pretty straightforward,
Created a module with with di.xml to override Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
Then created a model to override class.